# Is complete control over tagging me on Facebook possible?

Tags: facebook, facebook-tags, facebook-privacy

Facebook allows me to approve all photos where I am tagged to appear on my timeline. However, Facebook states:

> Note: This only controls what's allowed on your timeline. Posts you're tagged in still appear in search, news feed and other places on Facebook

Is there any option that will give me *full* control of all content where I am tagged? I don't like other people having power over what is published about me.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: no.

You can only block tagged photos from appearing in your timeline until they are approved, or remove your tags *after* they were posted. But it is not possible to prevent your friends from tagging you in their own photos.

Comment: Thank you. But will I find out about all the stuff I am tagged in? Will all my tags show up right away after being created with the request of being approved or deleted? Will they show up in something like my "to-approve list"? That would be at least some remedy to the problem, because I can delete them afterwards.